# Need to display Sub category list on custom page

Tags: magento2, category

I need to display Sub categories of current clicked category on custom page. How can I achieve this?

In short, If I explain my main category is displayed in menu, when I click on main category menu a page needs to be opened in which it subcategories will be displayed.

Comment: you want to show sub category on any custom page

Comment: you need first level category of your clicked current category ?

Comment: Yes I want to show sub category on custom page when clicked on main category